# Log of remote history

Tags: git

I have been asked to make a log of all the pushes made to a remote repository during a working day to display along side our build information. I am having trouble getting the necessary information for the remote repository.

I can get the info in relation to my local version of the repository with "$git log", and I have come close with the command "$git reflog show origin/master" on the remote but the main problem here is that it shows no details.

My remote repository is hosted on BitBucket. I am trying to get the list of files that have been pushed and the commit message associated with that push, across the whole day. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried looking at Bitbucket API? This looks like something that can suite your needs: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/changesets+Resource#changesetsResource-GETalistofchangesets

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```sh
git log origin
```

This will give you a log of commits on the `origin` remote.

[`git-log(1)`](http://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Comment: Be aware that a commit is different from a push! git log only shows you commits. It does not show you who pushed the commit and when. (There usually are many potentially old commits in a single push from today.)

Comment: This command also only lists commits that have been fetched. It does not actually contact the remote.

Answer (score 6):

You have first to fetch the remote branch into your local remotes/origin. Then you can log this. For instance, if you are working on branch master:

```
git fetch
git log FETCH_HEAD
```

This will now show you the log from remotes/origin/master on your local machine.

Comment: is there any means to actually query the remote server from a local context _without_ fetching even a bare repo? In other words is there a means to run a `git log` or `git diff` command on the remote that leaves no trace on the local file system?